# rubyのarrayのeachで代入する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: ruby

```
ary = [[10,15,'s'], [20,25], [30,35]] 
ary.each do |elm1, elm2, elm3| 
elm1=elm1/5 
end 
p ary
```

結果が`[[10, 15, "s"], [20, 25], [30, 35]]`になります。
`[[2, 15, "s"], [4, 25], [6, 35]]`にする方法を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLUEPIXYさんご自身のコメントにもありますが、 `map!` が自然じゃないかと思います。

```
ary.map! {|a| [ a[0]/5, *a.drop(1) ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

今更ではありますが、、、。
Eachでは値を持って来るだけなので、each_index で配列にアクセスしなおす。ということになると思います。
僕もはまりました、、、、。

```
ary.each_index {|idx|
  ary[idx][0] = ary[idx][0]/5
}
```

Comment: ruby 2.5.3で速度を計測してみましたが、こっちの方が速いですね。まあ、大きな配列を使わなければ微々たる差ですけど。あと、「ary.each_index { |i| ary[i][0] /= 5 }」の方が更に微妙に速いようです。

Answer (score 1):

例：

```
ary.each do |elm| 
    elm[0] /= 5
end
```

Comment: 変更？ 代入的にはmap! ？